# google ml kit instalation package:google_ml_kit_example

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I managed to get the following to work
(https://pub.dev/packages/learning_text_recognition)

but I can't install  google ml kit
(https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit)

but I can't install C:\projet_flutter\lectureimg2\android\app\build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.lectureimg2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

I have also modified

(https://www.cjoint.com/doc/21_10/KJCh5NwM74v_Capture.PNG)

but the pakage google ml_kit exeample and unknown
https://www.cjoint.com/doc/21_10/KJChYG31KNv_Capture.PNG

well I don't know what to try to test mlkit from google

merci pour tout aide même partiel

cdl remy

Comment: Have you reached out the authors of "google ml kit" flutter plugin (which is neither owned nor endorsed by Google or ML Kit) through their report issue page: https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin

Answer (score 0):

to install google mlkit you have to follow these instructions: [Text Recognition](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android).

As it says, you have to add it to your application dependencies

```
dependencies {
      // ...
      // Use this dependency to bundle the model with your app
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:17.0.0'
    }
```

And it's done!